# How to avoid re-initializing component when multiple linked routes use same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react-router-dom component that was all working fine in v5, and I have since upgraded to v6. In the below router structure, I have a single component that is accessed via different routes. This view has a playback feature that updates the URL when playback is stopped resulting in a `foo/<fooId>/<time>` url structure, and a means to link to something in the list with `bar/<barId>`. Both of these render the same component,   that uses the params as need be and can handle both entry points.

The issue I'm seeing since moving to v6 is it will refresh if switching from `foo/<fooId>/<time>` to `bar/<barId>` or viceversa. Same happens if I click a link to `bar/<barId>` while on `foo/<foodId>/time`. It's the same component, and simply updated the browser URL in the past (used to use `history.pushState` and now use `navigate` (from `useNavigate`), I tried adding a replace param, etc., but it still re-mounts the entire component.

How can I avoid this? I can only think to re-structure the pages, but there's a bunch of bookmarks out there that will be very unhappy, haha.

```
      <Route
        path="/foo"
        element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} element={<Bar />} />}
      >
        <Route
          path=":fooId"
          element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} element={<Bar />} />}
        />
        <Route
          path=":fooId/:timestamp"
          element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} element={<Bar />} />}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/bar">
        <Route
          path=":barId"
          element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} element={<Bar />} />}
        />
      </Route>
```

AuthRoute:

```
function AuthedRoute({ authState, element }) {
  const location = useLocation()
  const { isLoggedIn } = authState
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    element
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to="/login"
      state={{
        from: location,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Similar structure to the example [here](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f)

Comment: What is this `AuthedRoute` component doing with the `element` prop that is passed to it? Looks like its the cause of the remounting. Can you add the `AuthedRoute` component to your question?

Comment: Added the AuthedRoute description

Comment: Does the issue repro if you convert `AuthedRoute` to a layout component rendering an `Outlet` instead of the passed `element` prop rendered into a `Route` *and* wrap the routes and have the routes render `element={<Bar />}` directly?

Comment: Will try this now

Comment: I'll try reproducing in a codesandbox as well, see if it can be resolved.

Comment: New Implementation:
`
function AuthedRoute({ authState }) {
  const location = useLocation()
  return authState.isLoggedIn ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to="/login"
      state={{
        from: location,
      }}
    />
  )
}
`

`
<Route path="/foo" element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} />}>
        <Route path=":fooId" element={<Bar />} />
        <Route path=":fooId/:time" element={<Bar />} />
</Route>
      <Route path="/bar">
        <Route path=":barId" element={<Bar />} />
</Route>
`

Same behavior (but prefer this syntax)

Comment: @DrewReese my gut feels like this may either be a bug in `react-router` or an unsupported setup. I can try to make a codesandbox as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot, ok, I hadn't noticed that you had nested "/foo" and "/bar" routes. That changes things a bit. I was able to reproduce the issue of switching between "/foo" and "/bar" routes. I still suggest converting the `AuthedRoute` into a layout component and rendering an `Outlet` for nested routes you want to protect.

```
function AuthedRoute({ authState }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { isLoggedIn } = authState;
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to="/login"
      state={{
        from: location
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Next is to configure/structure your routes so the are correctly nested. The following structure seems to work as you are expecting.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AuthedRoute authState={authState} />}>
    <Route path="/foo/*">
      <Route index element={<Bar />} />
      <Route path=":fooId" element={<Bar />} />
      <Route path=":fooId/:timestamp" element={<Bar />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/bar/*">
      <Route path=":barId" element={<Bar />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login /* auth props? */ />} />
</Routes>
```

For testing when `Bar` component was mounted vs rendered (*an `id` prop was passed to each to identify them*):

```
const Bar = ({ id }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Bar MOUNTED!!", { id });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Bar Rendered!!", { id });
  }, [id]);

  return <h1>Bar</h1>;
};
```

After authenticating, use the links to navigate between all the different routes and note when "Mounted" vs "Rendered" logs.

Here's my running codesandbox:

[image: Edit how-to-avoid-re-initializing-component-when-multiple-linked-routes-use-same-comp]